# Using .Net's built-in authentication in iOS applications

Tags: .net, ios

I have written a web application that uses Microsoft's built-in membership authentication that is connected to a SQL server. I was wondering what would be the best way to use this same database for authenticating users from an iOS application? Ultimately, I want to create a login panel that the application opens with, that will authenticate the username/password against the membership database that I have already.

Is this possible, or is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write an ASP.NET or WCF web service that abstracts out your database calls that uses the same membership provider configuration.